# how do I print the value of an object in php without doing $foo->value?

Tags: php, string, variables, object

I want to be able to get the value of a php object without having to do `$foo->value`. Similar to how a variable works ex.

```
$foo = "bar";
print $foo;
```

The line printed is `bar`.

Answer (score 1):

There's no such thing as a "default value" for an object, so this doesn't work. The closest you can get is with the [magic `__toString` method](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#language.oop5.magic.tostring), which controls as what kind of string value the object is printed in a string context.

Comment: +1 - This is the only way that you can make a default output for an object.  To add to that...this works great for anything to do with strings, but will not work for mathematical operations.  If you want to do $type + $type, they need to be a base type.

Comment: @KevinNelson: `1 + (string) $foo` - you can cast to string for that. Not saying you should do this, but this is how it does work with `__toString`.

Comment: @hakre - interesting...never in my wildest dreams would I think to cast something to a string in order to get it to work as a number...haha...still would probably never do it since it would lack clarity, but interesting nonetheless.

Comment: @KevinNelson: Well it's not that straight-forward with loosely typed systems sometimes :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`print_r()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) or [`var_dump()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) or [`var_export()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php) to get a textual representation of your object.

Each of those functions is used by passing in an expression; it could be an object, an array, or a value.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for extract()

```
extract($foo);
print $value1;
print $value2;
print $value3;
```